# Mount.nfs: how to capture connection timed out

Tags: rhel, mount, nfs

On my main host I have a directory `/exported_dir` which I'd like to share with another host. To do this I execute:

```
mount <host>:/exported_dir /mount_dir
```

Connection times out and I am not able to capture it. I tried to save the output inside a variable: `mountres=$(mount <host>:/exported_dir /mount_dir)` and the value of `mountres` is an empty string. I also tried to redirect the output: `mount <host>:/exported_dir /mount_dir > mountmsg` but there is nothing inside `mountmsg`. OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server; Version: 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture both standard output and standard error streams then redirect standard error into standard output:

```
mountres="$(mount <host>:/exported_dir /mount_dir 2>&1)"

mount <host>:/exported_dir /mount_dir >mountmsg 2>&1
```

Comment: forgot to redirect the `stderr`. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Command to diagnose connection time out:

`sudo mount -vvv -t <mount_type> <host>:/exported_dir /mount_dir`

or

`sudo mount -vvv -t <mount_type> -o vers=3 <host>:/exported_dir /mount_dir`

This issue occurs when NFS server doesn't respond properly.